# How to copy text including the "href" from SimpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml

I am setting up an automated API from a ticketing website that returns XML, to another ticketing website through an API. Text is looped through and copied exactly as expected; however, certain items have URLs associated with them, and the URLs are not copied over.

For example ($this->DETAILS->SOLUTION)
XML:

```
<SOLUTION>
<![CDATA[
<P>Patch:<BR> Following are links for downloading patches to fix the vulnerabilities: <P> <A HREF="http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fd2216eb-283b-4a23-b259-018a7fa5fe47" TARGET="_blank">MS12-036: Windows XP Service Pack 3</A><P> <A HREF="http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6e354955-32ae-447c-b16f-960acc01773b" TARGET="_blank">MS12-036: Windows XP Professional x64 Edition Service Pack 2</A>
]]>
</SOLUTION>
```

Output from my API:

> Patch:
>
> Following are links for downloading patches to fix the vulnerabilities:
>    MS12-036: Windows XP Service Pack 3 MS12-036: Windows XP Professional x64 Edition Service Pack 2 MS12-036: Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 MS12-036: Windows Server 2003 x64 Edition Service Pack 2 MS12-036: Windows Server 2003 with SP2 for Itanium-based Systems MS12-036: Windows Vista Service Pack 2 MS12-036: Windows Vista x64 Edition Service Pack 2 MS12-036: Windows Server 2008 for 32-bit Systems Service Pack 2 MS12-036: Windows Server 2008 for x64-based Systems Service Pack 2 MS12-036: Windows Server 2008 for Itanium-based Systems Service Pack 2 MS12-036: Windows 7 for 32-bit Systems MS12-036: Windows 7 for 32-bit Systems Service Pack 1 MS12-036: Windows 7 for x64-based Systems MS12-036: Windows 7 for x64-based Systems Service Pack 1 MS12-036: Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems MS1

Note:
This API is sending the new ticket via POST as an array.

I have not been successful at finding a way to do this.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

  foreach ($xml->TICKET_LIST->TICKET as $ticket) {

    --Skipping non-important code (not using echo in code, but making an example)
    echo $ticket->DETAILS->SOLUTION

}


No errors. Expected copied text to act as a hyperlink where applicable.
```

Comment: The character data (CDATA) in the `<SOLUTION>` contains HTML (*not* XML). Echoing it verbatim *within* XML output invalidates the XML output. This is technically problematic, however the example you give in the question is incomplete and therefore what you ask about is hard to verify which leads to guessing which is very problematic as it can often be read as harsh or questioning or criticizing, especially by new contributors. The help section of the site should guide you to improve your question. If not, please leave a comment here.

Comment: So I put echo as an example which may have been a mistake. $ticket->DETAILS->SOLUTION is stored in a variable which is then sent in an array to a ConnectWise API call.

Comment: This shows the important of creating a [mcve] - we should be able to actually run the simplified code you give us, and see the problem.